# How can I upgrade to Java SE Development Kit 9.0.1 on an AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, java

Tried with

```
[ec2-user@server ~]$ sudo yum install java-1.9.0
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No package java-1.9.0 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

so checked for the package but it's not there

```
[ec2-user@server ~]$ sudo yum list java*
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Installed Packages
java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64   1:1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1  @amzn-updates
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 1:1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1  @amzn-updates
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64  1:1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1  @amzn-updates
javapackages-tools.noarch   0.9.1-1.5.amzn1 installed
Available   Packages
java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64   1:1.6.0.41-1.13.13.1.77.amzn1   amzn-main
java-1.6.0-openjdk-demo.x86_64  1:1.6.0.41-1.13.13.1.77.amzn1   amzn-main
java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 1:1.6.0.41-1.13.13.1.77.amzn1   amzn-main
java-1.6.0-openjdk-javadoc.x86_64   1:1.6.0.41-1.13.13.1.77.amzn1   amzn-main
java-1.6.0-openjdk-src.x86_64   1:1.6.0.41-1.13.13.1.77.amzn1   amzn-main
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64   1:1.7.0.151-2.6.11.0.74.amzn1   amzn-main
java-1.7.0-openjdk-demo.x86_64  1:1.7.0.151-2.6.11.0.74.amzn1   amzn-main
java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 1:1.7.0.151-2.6.11.0.74.amzn1   amzn-main
java-1.7.0-openjdk-javadoc.noarch   1:1.7.0.151-2.6.11.0.74.amzn1   amzn-main
java-1.7.0-openjdk-src.x86_64   1:1.7.0.151-2.6.11.0.74.amzn1   amzn-main
java-1.8.0-openjdk-demo.x86_64  1:1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1  amzn-updates
java-1.8.0-openjdk-javadoc.noarch   1:1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1  amzn-updates
java-1.8.0-openjdk-javadoc-zip.noarch   1:1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1  amzn-updates
java-1.8.0-openjdk-src.x86_64   1:1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1  amzn-updates
java_cup.noarch 1:0.10k-5.7.amzn1   amzn-main
java_cup-javadoc.noarch 1:0.10k-5.7.amzn1   amzn-main
java_cup-manual.noarch  1:0.10k-5.7.amzn1   amzn-main
javacc.noarch   4.1-0.5.8.amzn1 amzn-main
javacc-demo.noarch  4.1-0.5.8.amzn1 amzn-main
javacc-manual.noarch    4.1-0.5.8.amzn1 amzn-main
javassist.noarch    3.9.0-6.4.amzn1 amzn-main
javassist-javadoc.noarch    3.9.0-6.4.amzn1 amzn-main
```

is there a way to install it through yum?

Comment: What distro are you using? Is that just plain EC2 or beanstalk?

Comment: plain EC2. `[ec2-user@server ~]$ uname -a
Linux server 4.9.51-10.52.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Sep 29 01:16:19 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download RPM package directly from Oracle and install it via yum.

Go to download page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html
 and use link to RPM package:

```
wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.1+11/jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.rpm
sudo yum install jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.rpm
```